# Solve for $x: \ln(x+4)+\ln(x-2)=5$

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

> **Solve for x: $\ln(x+4)+\ln(x-2)=5$**

[image]

**Where do I go from here?** If there weren't four terms in the equation I would use the quadratic formula. How  can I solve for x?

### EDIT 1:

[image]

**Is this correct?**

### EDIT 2:

[image]

I have a negative number under the square root now, which is a problem... What does this mean? Does it simply mean that x is undefined? Or have a made a mistake somewhere?

### EDIT 3

[image]

> **Final Answer:** Answer **A** is the only correct answer, because answer B is undefined in the equation.

Comment: your constant is $-(e^5+8)$

Comment: Now it's time for the quadratic equation.

Comment: @Joffan Ah, thank-you! I'll try that. One sec..

Comment: @PeterWoolfitt Edited.

Comment: @McB Remeber that $a,b,c$ in the quad. formula are the coefficients in a polynomial, not the terms

Comment: @MathN00b Right! So $a=1, b=2,..$ Does $c=-(e^5+8)$?

Comment: @McB Right. Remember there should be no $x$ term on the right hand side of the quadratic formula.

Comment: @SRX Thanks- here it goes...

Comment: After you use the Quadratic Formula (correctly), you need to check whether the two logarithms are defined at the solutions you get.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I don't think they are defined.. I got a negative under the square root.. What does that mean?

Comment: Algebra troubles, inside the square root you should get $2^2-4(-8-e^5)$, that is, $36+4e^5$, very positive. There are two solutions. One of them is fine, the other is not.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Think I might have finally gotten it..

Comment: Yes, you've got it.  The answer B doesn't work because (for example) $\ln(x-2)$ is not defined there, indeed neither is $\ln(x+4)$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Makes sense. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You are welcome. Careful about algebraic manipulations, in particular minus signs.